# Why would I use ratio estimation instead of regression estimation to estimate means?

Tags: regression, estimation, survey, ratio

I am taking a graduate course on survey data analysis. I was recently introduced to ratio estimation and regression estimation.

I understand that using ratio estimator may be easier if we are interested in:

1. the ratio of two variables
2. total of a variable (if $N$ is not available to estimate it using $N*\mu_x$ or if auxiliary variable is correlated to $y$.

I do not see how ratio estimation can be favourable (over regression estimation) if we are interested in estimating the mean of a variable. While using ratio estimation we have only a further 'assumption' that intercept is 0.

Is it possible that this 'assumption' actually holds but is not captured by a regression model with an intercept around zero? If not, is it not always a worse choice to use ratio estimation to estimate a mean?